# Encoding/Decoding using ESAPI

Tags: java, encoding, encoder, esapi

I  am trying to prevent CRLF injection(in a url having few user inputs) and trying to encode the user input present in URL. I know I can use input-validation too but if I use ESAPI encoder, does it have any corresponding decoder? If it has then what it is? If not then what can be done to perform the same encoding and decoding?

Comment: Fixed grammer and changed title to be less verbose

Answer (score 1):

As you alluded to, this is a task for the input validation. The ESAPI encoders do ***output*** encoding. There are no corresponding *decoders* because the decoding process (to render it as safe HTML) is done via the end user's browsers.

Comment: Thank you Kevin W.Wall
@smac89 dont mind my ignorance as i am new to this . 
Thanks all. Cheers.